# Set multiple price for single store view in magento

Tags: magento2, price, multistore

I want to set 3 different currency for a single store in Magento 2.
For e.g i have one store i.e store 1
I want to set 3 currency for this store for e.g Dollar, indian rupee and Euro.
On frontend there will be currency convertor or something similar to that.
Does this can be achieved with default functionality or using any extension.?
My main concern is setting multiple prices for single product in single store view.

Comment: There is a currency converter by default in magento. Also you can set currency rates for different currency. So, if you switch currency it will automatically changes price in all places.set currency rates https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/currency-update.html

Answer (score 2):

To set 3 different currency for a single store in Magento 2, You have to select the currencies from

> Admin->Stores->Configuration->General->Currency Setup

And in **Allowed Currency**, you can select multiple currencies as you want.

[image]

Then you have to set the Currency rates as default currency from

> Admin->Stores->Currency->Currency Rates

[image]

At last flush the cache and you will see the Currency switcher on the frontend header as below image.

[image]

Hope this will help you.